# How to get the shelveset associated to queued CIs?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, shelveset

Imagine this:

You have an Azure DevOps 2019 server and a XAML Build definition.

You queue a few check-ins to the build definition. The first one is in progress of being checked in, the rest are waiting in queue.

**How does one using the REST API get the shelvesets of the queued builds?**

It's easy to get the shelveset associated with the InProgress build, because there's a BuildID present. I use it to get more details on the build using the API, e.g.: "Builds/33217/Details".
From there on, I can get to the shelveset.

If a build is queued (or NotStarted), then the build details API returns:

```
{
"value": [],
"count": 0
}
```

... and therefore I cannot get the shelveset.

I was under the impression that a upgrade to DevOps 2019 amends the API, so that one can easily get the queued shelveset from XAML build definitions as well. However, I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Should I be using another API?

Comment: In non-xaml builds I can get reulsts in NotStarted api, maybe the issue that it's xaml?

Comment: Hello Howie did you try my options below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer ref [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/need-a-more-efficient-way-to-find-a-changeset-in-a/124948) *backlogged/doesn't exist/no easy way* explained in option `1`, but I used option `2`, and option `3`, I hope this [helps you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#queueoptions), I struggled a good bit!

> 1. Underlying issue is that you're querying from 1) `Bottom to Top in DevOps build Hierarchy/Object Model`, and you need to 2) `Associate the shelveSets versioned changeSet` & then to the build.

> #### 2. TLDR, I simply followed a `practice of prefixing/Tags` from my `shelveSets` allowing me to custom query the build as listed in option `3`. This allowed me to simplify it a good bit in the REST API Query `tagFilters={tagFilters}` for e.g. `ShelveSetBuildTag-....`

```
 // now modify you REST API filter `ShelveSetBuildTag-....` 
 GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&queues={queues}&buildNumber={buildNumber}
  &tagFilters={tagFilters}&buildIds={buildIds}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&api-version=6.0
```

---

**Option 1:** No example so, *MS build docs was clear as mud* for me, and was [not helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but its listed as possible, I *gave up and took a different route*, below..
[image: Azure Devops Shelvesets RESTAPI]

---

**Option 2:**

#### since `shelveSet`s are *unversioned* Azure DevOps uses versioned `changeSets` per their [ER/DB Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-build-changeset?view=azure-devops-2020) , `I had to get the associated shelveSets via ChangeSets/or WorkItems in a build.`

First, a nice article I found to help me understand the relationship and [difference between two key items, `changeSet` vs `shelveSet` Azure DevOps](http://vikasnetdev.blogspot.com/2013/03/tfs-version-control.html#:%7E:text=A%20changeset%20is%20a%20group,list%20of%20associated%20work%20items.&text=Unlike%20a%20changeset%2C%20a%20shelveset%20is%20a%20non%2Dversioned%20entity.) in relation to a **build**. The `changeSet` will allow you to *find associated* `shelvesets` to build, query it and get `DimChangeset`, I suspect you have to do this in a couple of steps.

> [image: FactBuildChangeset] picture below is associated with the following  dimension tables:
>
> - DimBuild
> - DimChangeset
> - DimPerson
> - DimTeamProject

[image: Picture to show Azure Devops ER Changeset has a relationship with Build Per MSDN]

IMHO versioning allows you get your `changeset associated with a build`, and then you can get the shelveset that went into that changeset

---

Step 1: get [changetSets for a ShelveSet](http://GET%20https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets/changes?shelvesetId=My%20first%20shelveset;d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db&api-version=6.0)

> GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets/changes?shelvesetId=My first shelveset;d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db&api-version=6.0

Step 2: get

> GET the [changes in a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
> https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version={version}

Step 3: I `manually join` the Response in my middle ware

---

**option 3:**

## Follow a `practice of tagging` your `shelveSets`

## Then, you query, using tags filer: `tagFilters={tagFilters}` in your build query

Use the tags from your shelvesets and filter from your builds list `tagFilters={tagFilters}` , of course this assume you setup tags

> ```
> // ``tagFilters={tagFilters}``for your shelveset assuming you set those up
> ```

> ```
> GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&queues={queues}&buildNumber={buildNumber}&minTime={minTime}&maxTime={maxTime}&requestedFor={requestedFor}&reasonFilter={reasonFilter}&statusFilter={statusFilter}&resultFilter={resultFilter}&tagFilters={tagFilters}&properties={properties}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&maxBuildsPerDefinition={maxBuildsPerDefinition}&deletedFilter={deletedFilter}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&branchName={branchName}&buildIds={buildIds}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&api-version=6.0
> ```